# ANTLR Grammar for Liquid Markup?

Tags: antlr, liquid

Anyone know of any ANTLR grammar for Liquid Markup or a JAVA library that can work with it? I have taken a look at [Jangod](http://code.google.com/p/jangod) but it doesn't seem to work much.

Thanks!

Comment: Liquid looks identical to Django's templating language....is there a correlation?

Comment: Yes, Django uses the liquid markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a grammar:

```
grammar Liquid;

options {
  output=AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
  ASSIGNMENT;
  ATTRIBUTES;
  BLOCK;
  CAPTURE;
  CASE;
  COMMENT;
  CYCLE; 
  ELSE;
  FILTERS;
  FILTER;
  FOR_ARRAY;
  FOR_RANGE;
  GROUP;
  IF;
  INCLUDE;
  LOOKUP;
  OUTPUT;
  PARAMS;
  PLAIN;
  RAW;
  TABLE;
  UNLESS;
  WHEN;
  WITH;
}

@parser::members {
  @Override
  public void reportError(RecognitionException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
  }
}

@lexer::members {
  private boolean inTag = false;

  private boolean openTagAhead() {
    return input.LA(1) == '{' && (input.LA(2) == '{' || input.LA(2) == '\u0025');
  }

  @Override
  public void reportError(RecognitionException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
  }
}

/* parser rules */
parse
 : block EOF -> block
 ;

block
 : (options{greedy=true;}: atom)* -> ^(BLOCK atom*)
 ;

atom
 : tag
 | output
 | assignment
 | Other -> ^(PLAIN Other)
 ;

tag
 : raw_tag
 | comment_tag
 | if_tag
 | unless_tag
 | case_tag
 | cycle_tag
 | for_tag
 | table_tag
 | capture_tag
 | include_tag
 ;

raw_tag
 : TagStart RawStart TagEnd raw_body TagStart RawEnd TagEnd 
   -> ^(RAW raw_body)
 ;

raw_body
 : ~TagStart*
 ;

comment_tag
 : TagStart CommentStart TagEnd comment_body TagStart CommentEnd TagEnd 
   -> ^(COMMENT comment_body)
 ;

comment_body
 : ~TagStart*
 ;

if_tag
 : TagStart IfStart expr TagEnd block else_tag? TagStart IfEnd TagEnd 
   -> ^(IF expr block ^(ELSE else_tag?))
 ;

else_tag
 : TagStart Else TagEnd block 
   -> block
 ;

unless_tag
 : TagStart UnlessStart expr TagEnd block else_tag? TagStart UnlessEnd TagEnd 
   -> ^(UNLESS expr block ^(ELSE else_tag?))
 ;

case_tag
 : TagStart CaseStart expr TagEnd when_tag+ else_tag? TagStart CaseEnd TagEnd 
   -> ^(CASE expr when_tag+ ^(ELSE else_tag?))
 ;

when_tag
 : TagStart When expr TagEnd block 
   -> ^(WHEN expr block)
 ;

cycle_tag
 : TagStart Cycle cycle_group? expr (Comma expr)* TagEnd 
   -> ^(CYCLE ^(GROUP cycle_group?) expr+)
 ;

cycle_group
 : expr Col -> expr
 ;

for_tag
 : for_array
 | for_range    
 ;

for_array // attributes must be 'limit' or 'offset'!
 : TagStart ForStart Id In lookup attribute* TagEnd block TagStart ForEnd TagEnd
   -> ^(FOR_ARRAY Id lookup ^(ATTRIBUTES attribute*) block)
 ;

attribute 
 : Id Col expr -> ^(Id expr)
 ;

for_range
 : TagStart ForStart Id In OPar expr DotDot expr CPar TagEnd block TagStart ForEnd TagEnd
   -> ^(FOR_RANGE Id expr expr block)
 ;

table_tag // attributes must be 'limit' or 'cols'!
 : TagStart TableStart Id In Id attribute* TagEnd block TagStart TableEnd TagEnd
   -> ^(TABLE Id Id ^(ATTRIBUTES attribute*) block)
 ;

capture_tag
 : TagStart CaptureStart Id TagEnd block TagStart CaptureEnd TagEnd
   -> ^(CAPTURE Id block)
 ;

include_tag
 : TagStart Include a=Str (With b=Str)? TagEnd 
   -> ^(INCLUDE $a ^(WITH $b?))
 ;

output
 : OutStart expr filter* OutEnd 
   -> ^(OUTPUT expr ^(FILTERS filter*))
 ;

filter
 : Pipe Id params? 
   -> ^(FILTER Id ^(PARAMS params?))
 ;

params
 : Col expr (Comma expr)*  -> expr+
 ;

assignment
 : TagStart Assign Id EqSign expr TagEnd 
   -> ^(ASSIGNMENT Id expr)
 ;

expr
 : or_expr
 ;

or_expr
 : and_expr (Or^ and_expr)*
 ;

and_expr
 : eq_expr (And^ eq_expr)*
 ;

eq_expr
 : rel_expr ((Eq | NEq)^ rel_expr)*
 ;

rel_expr
 : term ((LtEq | Lt | GtEq | Gt)^ term)?
 ;

term
 : Num
 | Str
 | True
 | False
 | Nil
 | lookup
 ;

lookup
 : Id (Dot Id)* -> ^(LOOKUP Id+)
 ;

/* lexer rules */
OutStart : '{{' {inTag=true;};
OutEnd   : '}}' {inTag=false;};
TagStart : '{%' {inTag=true;};
TagEnd   : '%}' {inTag=false;};

Str : {inTag}?=> (SStr | DStr);

DotDot : {inTag}?=> '..';
Dot    : {inTag}?=> '.';
NEq    : {inTag}?=> '!=';
Eq     : {inTag}?=> '==';
EqSign : {inTag}?=> '=';
GtEq   : {inTag}?=> '>=';
Gt     : {inTag}?=> '>';
LtEq   : {inTag}?=> '<=';
Lt     : {inTag}?=> '<';
Pipe   : {inTag}?=> '|';
Col    : {inTag}?=> ':';
Comma  : {inTag}?=> ',';
OPar   : {inTag}?=> '(';
CPar   : {inTag}?=> ')';
Num    : {inTag}?=> Digit+;
WS     : {inTag}?=> (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();};

Id
 : {inTag}?=> (Letter | '_') (Letter | '_' | '-' | Digit)*
   {
     if($text.equals("capture"))          $type = CaptureStart;
     else if($text.equals("endcapture"))  $type = CaptureEnd;
     else if($text.equals("comment"))     $type = CommentStart;
     else if($text.equals("endcomment"))  $type = CommentEnd;
     else if($text.equals("raw"))         $type = RawStart;
     else if($text.equals("endraw"))      $type = RawEnd;
     else if($text.equals("if"))          $type = IfStart;
     else if($text.equals("endif"))       $type = IfEnd;
     else if($text.equals("unless"))      $type = UnlessStart;
     else if($text.equals("endunless"))   $type = UnlessEnd;
     else if($text.equals("else"))        $type = Else;
     else if($text.equals("case"))        $type = CaseStart;
     else if($text.equals("endcase"))     $type = CaseEnd;
     else if($text.equals("when"))        $type = When;
     else if($text.equals("cycle"))       $type = Cycle;
     else if($text.equals("for"))         $type = ForStart;
     else if($text.equals("endfor"))      $type = ForEnd;
     else if($text.equals("in"))          $type = In;
     else if($text.equals("and"))         $type = And;
     else if($text.equals("or"))          $type = Or;
     else if($text.equals("tablerow"))    $type = TableStart;
     else if($text.equals("endtablerow")) $type = TableEnd;
     else if($text.equals("assign"))      $type = Assign;
     else if($text.equals("true"))        $type = True;
     else if($text.equals("false"))       $type = False;
     else if($text.equals("nil"))         $type = Nil;
     else if($text.equals("include"))     $type = Include;
     else if($text.equals("with"))        $type = With;
   }
 ;

Other
 : ({!inTag && !openTagAhead()}?=> . )+
   {
     String s = getText().replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
     if(s.isEmpty()) {
       skip();
     }
     else {
       setText(s);
     }
   }
 ;

/* fragment rules */
fragment Letter : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z';
fragment Digit  : '0'..'9';
fragment SStr   : '\'' ~'\''* '\'';
fragment DStr   : '"' ~'"'* '"';

fragment CommentStart : ;
fragment CommentEnd : ;
fragment RawStart : ;
fragment RawEnd : ;
fragment IfStart : ;
fragment IfEnd : ;
fragment UnlessStart : ;
fragment UnlessEnd : ;
fragment Else : ;
fragment CaseStart : ;
fragment CaseEnd : ;
fragment When : ;
fragment Cycle : ;
fragment ForStart : ;
fragment ForEnd : ;
fragment In : ;
fragment And : ;
fragment Or : ;
fragment TableStart : ;
fragment TableEnd : ;
fragment Assign : ;
fragment True : ;
fragment False : ;
fragment Nil : ;
fragment Include : ;
fragment With : ;
fragment CaptureStart : ;
fragment CaptureEnd : ;
```

I have dusted the thing off a bit and put it in a Github repository: https://github.com/bkiers/Liqp

Be aware: although I have successfully used this grammar in the past, the input might have been rather "easy". If you're going to use it, and run into problems, I'd appreciate it if you let me know. If you're looking for a more robust, thoroughly tested library/parser/grammar, this might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Will surely let you know of my mileage.